# Why was the "How to launch a missile" question deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, april-fools

There was a funny question (["How to launch a missile?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711757/how-can-i-launch-a-missile)), highly upvoded by the community, that was closed and almost reopened before I went to bed. I woke up today to the fact that it was wiped off the face of the planet. It still shows up in Google Cache, but now Stack Overflow won't show it to me. Did the moderators decide to leave their sense of humor at home today and nuke it?

Comment: Did you sleep the entire *day*? That question was posted in the morning and deleted before noon!? If only I lived in another time zone I could sleep all day as well...

Comment: I think i'm in a different time zone than you :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, it was deleted by one of the mods (I'll let him speak up if he wants), and I congratulate him for it.

Frankly I find very few of these so-called "humor" questions funny at all.  The fact that 82 people voted it up only proves that 82 Stack Overflow users would laugh at Bob Saget.  Even if they are genuinely funny, they add no value to Stack Overflow as a Q&A site, so please don't complain when they get closed/deleted.

(Go ahead and downvote me for being a bitter old crank; I don't care, I'm leaving this post where it is.)

Comment: +1 from another bitter old crank. I like some of the humor, but this was just preposterous.

Comment: +1 for being a bitter old crank.

Comment: Which Bob Saget?  Full House/AFHV Bob, or so-offensive-I-won't-even-link-to-it-stand-up-comedy Bob?

Comment: Neither Bob is all that funny, but at least he tries hard to be diverse.

Comment: Looks like people had fun with it while it lasted. That makes me happy. But not as happy as seeing that it's gone...

Comment: @Bill: Good point, I meant AFHV Bob.

Comment: -1 for being a bitter old crank, but then +1 for being funny so it evens out :)

Comment: Who *doesn't* laugh at Bob Saget?!?  Oh, wait, did you mean laugh at his jokes, or him?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not a 10K user (so I can't see the original/deleted), and I can't find it in Google's cache. (Though I do see it [on search results](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+how+to+launch+a+missile).) The little text I have from Google reads:

> I am working on an open-source missile
> launcher application. ...  The people
> who closed this question should go
> back and read the SO FAQ: "bring your
> sense of ...

I'm going to guess that it was originally closed as "off topic." It may have also garnered offensive/spam votes.

The reality is that while a sense of humor is a good idea, it takes a **lot** to get something like that by the community. I'd have voted to shut it down in a heartbeat. It's obviously nothing but [a noisy joke](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/joke-questions-please-refrain/), and thus doesn't even provide much in the way of entertainment value to the community.

And before you mention other classic jokes on SO:

1. They are few and far between
2. Most are very old
3. The closest I can come to an example this "out there" is [Boat Programming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/) -- and that, too, was obliterated with extreme prejudice.

Comment: And boat programming was *actually* funny because it satirized the other off-topic questions.  It helped people to see that they had to draw the line somewhere - a line which I think seems to be getting gradually forgotten...

Comment: @Aarobot: I didn't say boat programming wasn't funny (I thought it was a riot), just that it was exterminated with extreme prejudice. :)

Comment: I didn't say that you said it wasn't funny; it was meant as a comparison to the question in question.

Answer (score 6):

This question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711757/how-can-i-launch-a-missile

is only available to 10k+ users, because it was deleted by Marc Gravell, a moderator.

It was deleted because it wasn't really programming related, and while humorous, really wasn't an acceptable question for Stack Overflow. While funny questions are alright sometimes, the community generally discourages them.

He posted the following comment before deleting it:

> Humour is one thing, but this simply isn't a sensible question. – Marc Gravell♦

If enough people want the question back, it can be undeleted by three users with over 10k reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You should of asked this question at the beginning of the month.  Joke questions are tolerated one day out of the year.

Comment: Why so much hate? I was suggesting April Fool's day.

Comment: Thanks to people who think AF is a good day for joke questions, SO is less usable on AF than during the rest of the year.