# Why are things closed as "not constructive?"

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons, not-constructive

Often the discussions raised in "not constructive" questions are extremely valuable.

Please don't be too heavy-handed with closing threads as not constructive.

At the end of the day, it's good content that exists on SO, that will earn you SEO and bring more people to your site.

Comment: Can you please post examples of such questions, where you feel the community has been heavy handed? As it stands, this question is not something anyone can answer - not without examples.

Comment: Related (dup?): [Why are useful questions on stackoverflow being closed as non-constructive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110350/why-are-useful-questions-on-stackoverflow-being-closed-as-non-constructive?rq=1)

Comment: `that will earn you SEO and bring more people to your site.` Stack Overflow doesn't have a problem with too few visitors. It may have one with  *too many*

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Not sure the databases agree with you.

Comment: @Oded Is this the DB runs at 25% cpu utilization thing?

Comment: @casperOne - Way to ruin it for me.

Comment: @Oded, how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406171/php-var-dump-vs-print-r
asks a factual question regarding differences in PHP output, received useful answers, closed as "not constructive" by 5 moderators!

Comment: @WiringHarness - what about it?

Comment: @Oded, that question was a factual question that received factual and useful answers, but five moderators closed as "not constructive".  Is that just because it had "vs" in the title?

Comment: @WiringHarness - could be. You would have to ask the closers. And the closers are **not** diamond moderators, just users with close privileges (gained with reputation).

Answer (score 1):

Not Constructive description:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A
>   format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or
>   specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate,
>   arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this
>   question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for
>   guidance.

It means that it's more of a discussion thread than a Q&A question

I agree that "Not constructive" isn't quite the best verbiage to use, but when you ask a "question" that doesn't actually seek a concrete answer, you can expect it to get closed as **not constructive**

Comment: "Not constructive" is extremely negative, especially when the description doesn't contain that word at all! Why can't be "Closed as not a good fit"?