# Can I completely delete my question?

Tags: discussion

It looks like deleted questions are just marked as deleted, but they aren't deleted from DB.

Is there some timefrime when they will be removed or do they stay permanently? If they are permament, is there any of deleting a question completely?

Answer (score 1):

Deleted questions are visible, but not searchable [for 10k+ users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). Questions never get deleted completely.

If you have a serious concern about your question (for instance you posted accidentally user credentials) then you can edit your question accordingly and flag for moderator attention and request a deletion of a specific revision of your post.

You can also ask that your name be [removed from the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki).

Comment: Well, except for the Boat Programming one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Come again?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131736.  Alas, it appears that all traces of the original question have been removed from all mirrors that used to host it.  It's the only question I know of that was actually obliterated with the heat of a thousand suns.