# What does it mean to have 'Jeff-level access'?

Tags: support, jeff-atwood

I was searching something on Meta and came across a (now deleted) [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22577/282626) on undeleting accounts, which used the phrase "Jeff-level access".

Can anyone explain what that phrase is supposed to mean?

Is it something related to [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)?

Comment: These days you can probably safely replace "Jeff" with "Shog" and have same effect. ;)

Comment: @Shadow Not at all; Shog does not have core developer access. [Case in point](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3247803#3247803)... "Because that's how I fix things now. I really love being a normal user."

Comment: @pizza well, shog can simply ask a dev for such access or "give me a View/Tool" for something. Same Same. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: "Can ask someone to do this and probably have them agree" **!=** "Can just go and do it".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't relevant anymore since 1. Jeff no longer works for Stack Exchange and 2. the answer this question is based on has since been deleted.

Comment: This question is still current (applicable) and has [a great answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253614/282094). Just because someone doesn't work here anymore doesn't mean that there's no replacement/ someone with equal permission levels and skills. --- There's no reason to close this as irrelevant.

Comment: This question has its own tag and pertains to a founder. The expression has no other hits in search, true, but if it were to be closed a "historical lock" would be appropriate - I don't think normal user CVs are the right choice here.

Comment: Answers in past tense. Its something a user *will* come across considering the footprint Jeff had in the early days as a BDFT (Benevolent Dictator for Tenure) and considering its been years since he left, new folks will not know. I think a closevote is un-necessarily pedantic, and completely un-necessary.

Comment: In 7 years there have only been 215 views. Proof that barely anyone has come across or needed to find out what the expression "Jeff-level acess"  means.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Just FYI, the answer was not yet written in the past tense at the time I voted to close. I agree that the edited version of the question doesn't deserve to be closed, but I'm wondering why you chose to clear the pending close votes given that [the question received a Leave Open outcome in close review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/83226) and got no external votes since. The general guidance here is that doing so is reserved for exceptional cases, so I'd like to know why you considered this case exceptional.

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні Views are not a factor in assessing whether a question is a good fit for the site or not.

Comment: There are [only two posts in the entire archive that refer to the *expression*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Jeff+level+access%22). The question  had sense 7 years ago but ONLY to the author asking. No one else has since asked about it or needed to find out more about the neologism.

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog well, that was a better solution.

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні and a few deleted ones. And chat. And possibly people too shy to ask

Comment: Famously (or infamously?), [Jeff deleted the boat programming question from the database](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131733/why-was-the-original-boat-programming-question-deleted#comment363617_131733). The question was talked about [in podcast episode 50](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131733/why-was-the-original-boat-programming-question-deleted#comment707056_131733) (second series?).

Comment: @Sonic so close 99.999% questions here on MSE because they're also not "relevant" anymore. Be it bugs that already been fixed, discussions about features that were removed or changed. Good luck. (Well, what I mean is obvious: let the past stay in the past. Please.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, Jeff Atwood was one of the founders of Stack Exchange as previously mentioned in Stack Exchange [Management Team page](https://stackoverflow.co/company/leadership):

> Jeff Atwood - Co-Founder (Emeritus)
>
> Jeff Atwood is a software developer, author, blogger, and entrepreneur. He is one of the co-creators of stackoverflow.com and one of the co-founders of Stack Exchange...

It means in order to solve the problem you need direct access to the internal SE database, which is limited to a few of the developers. So only SE employees can do that action. Since Jeff was the most well-known SE employee and founder, Bill called it 'Jeff-level access'.

Comment: How many employees had access in 2009? Possible it was *literally* Jeff level at the time.

Comment: That was crossing my mind too. I guess Joel has access too. And Jon Skeet (how did he get all that rep otherwise?)

Comment: @Air Joel is less a programmer and more a business man but yeah, looks like he could skim through the database if he wanted to. [Jarrod](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3/jarrod-dixon) has a lower ID than even Joel, so likely was a dev from very early stage as well.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yep, see [this old comment thread on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121498/now-that-jeff-atwood-is-moving-on-who-will-be-in-charge/121542#comment322072_121542). But "writing code" <> "database superuser" so we don't really know (not that it's important)