# Why do basic questions that show no signs of research or anything get hundreds of upvotes, but other detailed questions get downvoted?

Tags: discussion, questions, voting, down-votes

Exactly as the question title states, I see people on Stack Overflow ask "How does slicing work in Python?" and get 400 upvotes and all the answers have 600 + upvotes, but when some users try their best to ask the best possible questions they get downvoted because of grammar or small thing.

But at least the people in the latter class that do the research then come to Stack Overflow are showing it. Why do people who barely even ask a question get upvoted so easily, like the example? They can just do that quick Google search.

Comment: It is a paradox of Stack Overflow (observed since the beginning in 2008 and, I think, also mentioned in the first podcast series). There are *many* meta questions about it. What is the canonical meta question, incl. on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)? A recent one: *[Are users being disincentivized to care about posting good questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420339/)* (2022-09-12).

Comment: Why? Because there are users who dislike the concept of downvotes and will literally upvote spam. Yes; **I have literally seen spam upvoted.**

Comment: [Laziness is rewarded big time by the reputation system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271985/839601)

Answer (score 13):

I did a google for the phrase and found that [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing) was from 2009, 13 years ago.

[image]

So - if you had searched for the question at the time, there wouldn't have been a duplicate. There are a few factors here. We've refined what's acceptable here based on experience - consider the old [boat programming meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about) and our policies in general on [recommendation questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). Our quality standards have also gotten significantly stricter since then. You can't always judge the responses of users today based off the past.

I guess it feels unfair, but that's a 'perk' of being an early user.

Simply - it was a question that had never been asked before *then* and added to the knowledge base. You can refer back to it. You can even ask a new question if slicing has changed over new versions of Python changed the slicing syntax *referencing this question and its answers*. I've occasionally personally repackaged a bit of knowledge that I picked up elsewhere as a post on various sites so it’s findable here.

As such, a good many people googled "How does slicing work in Python" as I did, found the answer, and if they had the same problem, upvoted the question for *being there when they needed it* and any useful answers. As we often tell people—you're not asking a question just for you; you're asking a question for the next person with the same problem, or in this case the next 4336.

It’s not about grammar or spelling; it’s about answerability (there being a solvable problem), interestingness and effort. Yes, that was a simple question *from another time* - we've grown (huge!) and things work differently now.